# Querying a 3rd party website's database from my website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

## The Goal:

To retrieve information from a 3rd party database based off of a user's query on my ASP.NET website

## The Details:

I need to be able to search 3rd-party websites for information relating to pharmaceutical drugs. Basically, here's what I've been tasked with: a user starts entering the name of a drug they're using in their experiments, and while they're typing a 3rd party website (e.g., [here](http://www.drugbank.ca/) or [here](http://www.pharmgkb.org/index.jsp)) is queried and suggestions are made based off of what they've typed. Once they've made a selection,  certain properties (molecular weight, chemical structure, etc) are retrieved from the 3rd party database and stored in our database. `PharmaGKB.org`'s search bar is pretty much what I need to implement, but I need to access a 3rd party db. The site that I'm working on is ASP.NET/C#.

## The Problem:

I don't really know where to start with this. There's a downloadable Perl example at the bottom of the page [here](http://www.pharmgkb.org/downloads.jsp), but it didn't really help me all that much. I'm at a loss as to how to implement this, or even find information about how to do it. The AJAX toolkit was suggested, but I'm not sure if that will solve the issue. JavaScript is also being considered, but again, I'm not sure if that will be sufficient, either.

## Perl Example Connection

As a mentioned, here is a snippet from the Perl example given on the `Pharmgkb.org` site:

```
my $call = SOAP::Lite
-> readable (1)
-> uri('SearchService')
-> proxy('http://www.pharmgkb.org/services/SearchService')
-> search ($ARGV[0]);
```

However, I'm not sure how to implement this is C#/ASP.NET/JavaScript. There's a question on Stack Overflow about embedding Perl in C#, but it require a C wrapper as well, and I don't think that three languages is necessary or wise to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have security permission to query the 3rd party DBs? You probably don't, so you are pretty much left with screen scraping the site.

Comment: Supposedly these sites allow 3rd party access, `http://www.pharmgkb.org/` says: "Web Services: A selected subset of data from PharmGKB is accessible via a SOAP interface." I *think* this is what they're talking about.

Comment: Perfect. Then you want to first figure out the service's interface. It will probably be a page with an .asmx extension. Does the site give you that info?

Comment: Hmmm....I'm not sure if this is it, but there's: http://www.pharmgkb.org/page/soapSearchApi and http://www.pharmgkb.org/services/SearchService?wsdl.

Comment: I just looked at the API and that looks like what you need. I think your first step should be a test harness to POC the calls to the service.

Comment: Okay, Google didn't really help. I understand testing the calls to the db, but I'm unsure how I would go about that - i.e., connecting to the website before attempting to query it.

Comment: Add a web reference to your Visual Studio project, then from your code call the web reference as you would an internal class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from the comments to your post, here's what I think you can do:

1. Add a service reference to your Web project. In the Address, use this: http://www.pharmgkb.org/services/SearchService?wsdl.
2. Click Go. The wizard will recognize the service as SearchServiceService. In the Namespace textbox below, give the name 'SearchServiceReference'.
3. Your service methods and data objects would be created (along with all the other necessary bits to run your service).
4. Then, you can use the service reference like:

   > public static object[] Search(string searchString)
   >   {
   >
   > ```
   >         using (var searchSeviceClient = new SearchServiceReference.SearchServiceClient())
   >         {
   >             return searchSeviceClient.search(searchString);
   >         }
   >     }
   > ```

Also, considering the whole scenario of your problem, you would want this service to be run on text changed event of javascript/jQuery. You can learn how to call code-behind methods from jQuery using ajax in this article: [jquery ajax calling Wcf service or some method in Code behind from Client Side](http://blogs.effectlabs.com/post/2012/02/24/jquery-ajax-calling-Wcf-service-or-some-method-in-Code-behind-from-Client-Side.aspx)

Comment: So, this worked - kinda. I've been able to connect to the site and search (huge step forward, thank you so much) but there's some strange behavior. According to the API, the return value should be an array of `PharmGKB accession #,  type,  name,  PharmGKB URL` but querying the site with `search("Cisplatin")' returns an array of size 260. Am I missing something, or is this strange?

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get some way further. I tried to query the service and also received an array of 260 objects. By checking in firebug, it seems that the service is returning an array of objects, each object having at least four properties(probably the ones stated in their api document). So, what you must do is after receiving an array of objects from their service, try to cast each object to an array of strings and access the properties using index.